# Submit checkboxes with "Check All" button and clear validation error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, datatables, popover, datatables-1.10

Through much trial and error (mostly error), I have managed to incorporate jQuery Validate, Bootstrap 3 (using Popovers for validation messages), and DataTables to create I suspect a fairly common scenario:

A DataTable that contains a column of checkboxes, and offer a "check all" checkbox that selects all the checkboxes across pagination and filtering in a DataTable, and apply jQuery Validate to ensure a user doesn't submit without choosing at least one checkbox.

Here's a link to a live example of what I'm doing: http://live.datatables.net/lomelono/2/

It works (the script picks up all the checked checkboxes (either via the check all checkbox, or if manually chosen, and across pagination and filtering on the DataTable), and will validate if no checkbox is chosen.

What it doesn't do is:

- Clear the validation error if the check all checkbox is chosen

Another odd side effect by using `.appendTo()` to ensure all checked checkboxes across pagination/filtering are chosen for submit is all the checkboxes (checked or unchecked) will appear at the bottom of the form before submit (the submit is disabled on the example so you can see the behavior).

Obviously I know just enough jQuery to be dangerous, but is there a better way to submit all the checked checkboxes, AND ensure client-side validation works correctly? Of course, I have a server-side catch, but ideally we want to inform the user BEFORE they submit.

I think I am really close to solving this, and hopefully someone can point me towards the finish line, that will hopefully benefit others who have this kind or similar sort of scenario.

Comment: When I click "All" checkbox, form passes validation and no validation error needs to be cleared, can you please clarify?

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the fast response (I am reading your excellent article now) - What I meant is if you do NOT check the check all checkbox, try to submit, you will get as expected a validation error - clicking the check all checkbox does NOT clear this validation error, but will allow the form to submit. The check all checkbox should clear any validation errors.

Comment: I tried the steps you've mentioned, but both in Firefox and Chrome selecting "Check all" and clicking "Compose" makes popover disappear and I get checkboxes at the bottom which means that the form is about to be submitted.

Comment: I am using Chrome 44/Windows 7, and these are the steps I used:
Click Compose Email Button
Validation Error Message Appears
Click Check All checkbox
Validation message remains

Comment: I'm also using Chrome 44/Windows 7 and when I click "Check all" the message goes away, see [screenshot](http://imgur.com/uDCUI8K).

Comment: Very odd - even on my updated JSBin, the message does not go away. Just to rule out caching, I tried on Firefox (latest) which I never use, and the same behavior.

To be clear, you are clicking the Compose Email button first, getting the validation error message, then clicking the check all checkbox, and the message disappears for you?

Comment: That's correct. I also tried IE and your updated example and every time the popover disappears once I click "Compose Email" the second time after checking "Check All" checkbox.

Comment: AAAAH, OK - I see what you mean - I meant the validation error should clear when the check all checkbox is clicked, since at that point there shouldn't be any validation errors. I'm thinking the check all checkbox routine needs to make a call to the validation script so it can re-check the form. Correct?

Comment: Your rule `require_from_group: [1, '.memberID']` is satisfied when "Check all" is clicked and there is at least one checked checkbox. Very odd indeed that you still see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You may need to turn those `<input type="checkbox">` that are checked and don't exist in DOM into `<input type="hidden">` upon form submission.

For example:

```
$("#emailCompose").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {

       // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
       table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
          // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
          if(!$.contains(document, this)){
             // If checkbox is checked
             if(this.checked){
                // Create a hidden element 
                $(form).append(
                   $('<input>')
                      .attr('type', 'hidden')
                      .attr('name', this.name)
                      .val(this.value)
                );
             }
          } 
       });          
    //form.submit();
    },

    // ... skipped ...
});
```

#### DEMO

See [jQuery DataTables: How to submit all pages form data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/) for more details and demonstration.

Comment: I see from your excellent article you provided you use `.serialize()` - my issue with using that is when passed to my server-side script, I would have to deserialize it in some way (I am using ColdFusion as the server-side processing). ColdFusion will take duplicate inputs and provide the values comma-delimited. For example:

MemberID = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... etc.

I also found that `'serialize()` does NOT pass all checked values over filtering/pagination.

Comment: Using `.serialize()` for checkboxes only is alternative solution. The demo uses solution I described above. I'm using `.serialize()` to demonstrate on the front-end what parameters would be submitted to the server. The article is a work in progress, I will update it to clarify that.

Comment: It's an excellent article - amazing I didn't come across it in Googling how to solve this issue. I do see on your demo where it DOES pass all the checkboxes due to the code example you provided above. I'm going to give the above example a try.

Comment: I tried it, and it works perfectly! I've updated my JSBin with the updated code: http://live.datatables.net/lomelono/3/

Now, all that remains is the check all/validation issue...